# How can I override a property in a RealmObject using realm database?

Tags: c#, .net, realm, realm-database

I want to override the following property using Realm so I can trigger a `RaisePropertyChanged` for another property:

```
public int Reps { get; set; }
```

This doesn't work, because it does not get picked up by Realm as a column in the database:

```
private int _reps;
public int Reps
{
    get => _reps;
    set
    {
        RaisePropertyChanged("Reps");
        RaisePropertyChanged("RepsInfo");
        _reps = value;
    }
}
public int Reps { get; set; }
```

For what it's worth `RepsInfo` looks like this:

```
public string SetRepInfo { get => $"{Sets}x{Reps}"; }
```

The reason I want to do a `RaisePropertyChanged("RepsInfo")` is because all places where I'm using this object does not get an updated `SetRepInfo` when the `Reps` is updated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should instead override the `OnPropertyChanged` method. Adapting the example from the [docs](https://realm.io/docs/dotnet/latest/api/reference/Realms.RealmObject.html#Realms_RealmObject_OnPropertyChanged_System_String_) you need something like:

```
protected override void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
{
    if (propertyName == nameof(Reps))
    {
        RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(SetRepInfo));
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I'm gonna try that. Don't I need to call `base.OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)` as well?

Comment: The base implementation is a no-op, but sure, it's a good practice to always do that :)